# Set the spacing between axis label and axis ticks of a 3D surface plot created using Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

How to adjust the spacing between the axis label and axis ticks of a 3D surface plot created using Plotly, in python?

Answer (score 0):

It happen that I want the same thing for my graph. So to adjust the spacing  between the labels and to change also the ticks position and labeling we can push those configurations as a dictionary to the layout of the figure, by using `fig.update_layout()` method.

**Example**

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Surface(   
x = X, # 1D array
y = Y, # 1D array
z = Z, # 2D array
fig.update_layout(scene = dict(
                          xaxis = dict(
                                  ticktext= ['A','B','C'],
                                  tickvals= [0, 1, 2]
                          )
                 ))
fig.show()
```

**Note:** be sure to pass this configuration to a scene attribute.

**Link for Doc:** https://plotly.com/python/3d-axes/